# Multiple files process using Spring

Tags: spring

I have several files uploads in HTML.

```
<label for="app_snapshot_image_1">SNAPSHOT_1</label>
<input type="file" name="app_snapshot_image_1" id="app_snapshot_image_1" />
<label for="app_snapshot_image_2">SNAPSHOT_2</label>
<input type="file" name="app_snapshot_image_2" id="app_snapshot_image_2" />
<label for="app_snapshot_image_2">SNAPSHOT_3</label>
<input type="file" name="app_snapshot_image_3" id="app_snapshot_image_3" />
```

---

And this is spring controller processing multiparts request from WEB.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/apps/addOrModify/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
      public String testUpload(
            @RequestParam(required=false) MultipartFile app_snapshot_image_1,
            @RequestParam(required=false) MultipartFile app_snapshot_image_2,
            @RequestParam(required=false) MultipartFile app_snapshot_image_3) {
...
}
```

---

However, the above controller can process only 3 files named from app_snapshot_image_1 to 3; but this isn't what I want. I'd like to process unlimited files using the Controller.

Hope you understand my question and sorry for my little English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a model class with one field like below.

```
List<MultipartFile> files = LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList<MultipartFile>(),
                    FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(MultipartFile.class));
```

with its getter and setter. Now you need to pass this model as `@ModelAttribute` in the jsp where you are having a form for file uploading.

In JSP you need to create a new input for user to upload a new file using javascript and in the name attribute of the input tag you create specify value as `files[some int value]` in the square bracket specify the count of file control added by user in jsp.

And when you post the form with multiple files, in your controller you can have the same `@ModelAttribute` field to get the list filled with multiple files.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.